# Volume Slider like VLC

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls, slider

I am searching for Volume Slider that looks and behave just like VLC's slider.
[image]

I found the following post about how to style the slider: [Volume Slider CustomControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547248/volume-slider-customcontrol)
but I also want the same behavior...

What is the difference between the behaviors:
When you click on the slider [at the WPF] and move the mouse on the slider area (while mouse button still being hold) it should move the slider also to the position of the mouse on the slider.

I couldn't find how to do it.. maybe I should use something different than Slider?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a link to what a VLC slider and its behavior is?

Comment: @RBarryYoung: [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for help with here. Do you have a specific programming question?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan, Yes. How can I add behavior/s to the control?

Comment: @H.B.: Well, there's a lot of stuff at that site.  And since the word "slider" appears nowhere on that page, its still not at all clear what the OP means by "VLC Slider behavior" that is not already in the example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547248/volume-slider-customcontrol

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I think it's pretty understandable from the text in the question where the behavior is explained, and how the normal WPF slider behaves is very easy to find out if you don't know.

Comment: @Ron: By handling mouse events for example. I would not recommend doing that at the instance level, and the WPF slider is not really suited in terms of how it functions anyway, i'd write a new control.

Comment: @H.B.: Oops, you are right.  My bad..

Comment: I have styled WPF Sliders before and my recollection is that they ***do*** have the "drag and slide" behavior that is being described.  Is that not correct, or is it possible that the restyling at the link has just made the thumb-button too small/unselectable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a property on the slider called [IsMoveToPointEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.ismovetopointenabled.aspx) that sets the slider to the correct value but only when you click it doesn't update as you drag.

To update as you drag you have to update the value yourself when the mouse is moved, the method [Track.ValueFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.track.valuefrompoint.aspx) gives you the correct value, the track is part of the sliders template.

Example

```
public class DraggableSlider : Slider
{
    public DraggableSlider()
    {
        this.IsMoveToPointEnabled = true;
    }

    private Track track;
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        track = Template.FindName("PART_Track", this) as Track;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && track != null)
        {
            Value = track.ValueFromPoint(e.GetPosition(track));
        }
    }


    protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
        ((UIElement)e.OriginalSource).CaptureMouse();
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseUp(e);
        ((UIElement)e.OriginalSource).ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
}
```

The OnPreviewMouseUp/Down overrides capture the mouse, I tried VLC and that doesn't capture the mouse so you could remove them if you wanted. Capturing the mouse allows the value to change even if the mouse leaves the control similar to how scrollbars work.